# Why is port 22 showing connection refused when logging in using Ethernet?

Tags: server, ssh, ethernet

I have been facing a problem login into our server every time I switch from Wi-Fi connection to an Ethernet connection on my laptop. Using my laptop, I can easily connect via Wi-Fi but the problem begins when I try connecting the server using the Ethernet connection. Every time it shows the following error.

> ssh -X xxx@1223xxxx.ru
>
> ssh: connect to host 1223xxxx.ru port 22: Connection refused

Note:

1. Firewall settings checked
2. Ping 1223xxxx.ru possible by both Wi-Fi and Ethernet

Comment: Try `ssh -vvv xxx@1223xxxx.ru` It will give you a trace of the conversation.